# Beginner : Not understanding shape [,1] on Tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I want to make a model to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit with **Tensorflow.js** (with Node.js).

However, I am not understanding what *shapes* to use.

I have tried different `input_shape` such as `[1]`, `[1,20]` and finally set it to`[20]`
I also have tried different tensor shape for the Celsius & Fahrenheit arrays such as `tensor(celsius)`, `tensor([celsius])`.

Here is the code

```
var model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape:[20], units: 1}))

async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
    // Prepare the model for training.  
    model.compile({
      optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
      loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
      metrics: ['mse'],
    });

    const batchSize = 28;
    const epochs = 500;

    return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
      epochs,
      shuffle: true,
    //   callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
    //     { name: 'Training Performance' },
    //     ['loss', 'mse'], 
    //     { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
    //   )
    });
  }

c = tf.tensor([celsius]) // celsius = [1,2,3,4,...]
console.log(c.shape) // ==> [1,20]

f = tf.tensor([fahrenheit])
console.log(f.shape) // ==> [1,20]

trainModel(model, c, f)
```

Moreover, in the Python tutorial `input_shape` is `[1]` . With Node.js, only `[20]` seems to work.

The shape of inputs is `[1,20]` and it is correct.

Shape of labels is `[1,20]` as well but triggers following error :

Debugger says :

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have shape [,1], but got array with shape [1,20].
```

-
EDIT

Furthermore, when i try `input_shape: [1,20]`, it gives me :

```
expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 1,20
```

-

I expect the model to train by associating C° values to F° values.

Thank you

Comment: @joyzaza gives me `expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 1,20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:

```
{inputShape:[20], units: 1}
```

The model contains a single layer. `inputShape:[20]` which means batchInputShape that is `[null, 20]` will be the shape of the first layer. Likewise, `units: 1` indicates that the last layer will have the shape `[null, 1]`.

The features used have the shape [1, 20] matching therefore the batchInputShape of the model. However, that's not the case for the labels that have the shape `[1, 20]`. It has to have the shape `[1, 1]` therefore throwing the error:

> expected dense_Dense1 to have shape [,1], but got array with shape [1,20]

The units size of the model has to be changed to reflect the labels shape.

```
{inputShape:[20], units: 20}
```

Comment: The Python tutorial puts `units=1, input_shape=[1]`. I tried on Node but doesn't work. There is only ONE variable (repeated for different values) so wouldn't it be unit:1 and shape:1 ?

Comment: If you use, `{inputShape:[1], units: 1}`, then your features and labels should have the shape `[b, 1]`, b being the number of elements.